# SQL lookup table

Tags: sql, lookup-tables

My query is:

```
select 
    C.GradePoint, D.Domain
from
    (select 
         A.course_code, B.course_title, A.GradePoint
     from
         (select 
              course_code, GradePoint
          from 
              CoursesResult$
          where 
              roll_number = '42472' and GradePoint != 'I' 
              and GradePoint != 'F' and GradePoint != 'D-' 
              and GradePoint != 'D+' and GradePoint != 'D'
              and GradePoint != 'C-' and GradePoint != 'C'
              and GradePoint != 'C+') A  
     join Courses$ B on A.course_code=B.course_code) C 
     join Domains$ D on C.course_title=D.Courses
```

Output:

```
GradePoint         Domain
1.    B+        Software Developer
2.    B-        Software Developer
3.    B-        Software Developer
4.    B-        Project Management
5.    B-        Business Intelligence and Analytics
6.    B+        Business Intelligence and Analytics
7.    B+        Business Intelligence and Analytics
8.    B-        Game Development
9.    B             Game Development
10.    B-       Database Administrator
11.    B-       Database Administrator
12.    B        Database Administrator
```

now number for each grade is

1. B=3
2. B+ =4
3. B- = 2

I want to calculate the count of grades for each domain

Needed output:

1. Software Developer  8
2. Business Intelligence and Analytics  10
3. Database Administrator 7
4. and so on

Can anyone help??

Comment: So what's the exact problem?

Comment: i want to calculate the grade count against each domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace your first two lines with this:

```
select 
SUM(CASE C.GradePoint WHEN 'B' THEN 3 WHEN 'B+' THEN 4 WHEN 'B-' THEN 2 ELSE 0 END), 
D.Domain
```

And add `GROUP BY D.Domain` at the very end of the query